# Need to fix a issue that comming in antd tree component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using an antd tree component my issue is if you search something in the search bar then you will get search results in that result if you check and up check any field what happens all previous data get unchecked whatever data is present into the search bar result that only data remain selected if it already select or you just select what my task is I don't want to get unchecked all previously selected checked that only field update that we change right now I don't have any idea how can I fix this if anybody knows anyway, also I added a complete code SandBox link below.

This is my search bar filter code

```
const hasSearchTerm = (n, searchTerm) =>
  n.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
const filterData = (arr, searchTerm) =>
  arr?.filter(
    (n) =>
      hasSearchTerm(n.title, searchTerm) ||
      filterData(n.children, searchTerm)?.length > 0
  );

function filteredTreeData(data, searchString, checkedKeys, setExpandedTree) {
  let keysToExpand = [];
  const filteredData = searchString
    ? filterData(data, searchString).map((n) => {
        keysToExpand.push(n.key);
        return {
          ...n,
          children: filterData(n.children, searchString, checkedKeys)
        };
      })
    : data;
  setExpandedTree([...keysToExpand]);
  return filteredData;
}
```

This issue happens when the check or unchecks field after searching in the search bar in this part of the code

```
const onCheck = (checkedKeysValue) => {
    console.log("onCheck", checkedKeysValue);
    setCheckedKeys(checkedKeysValue);
  };
```

```
const Demo = () => {
  const [expandedKeys, setExpandedKeys] = useState([]);
  const [checkedKeys, setCheckedKeys] = useState([]);
  const [selectedKeys, setSelectedKeys] = useState([]);
  const [autoExpandParent, setAutoExpandParent] = useState(true);
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");
  const [tree, setTree] = useState(treeData);

  const onExpand = (expandedKeysValue) => {
    console.log("onExpand", expandedKeysValue); // if not set autoExpandParent to false, if children expanded, parent can not collapse.
    // or, you can remove all expanded children keys.

    setExpandedKeys(expandedKeysValue);
    setAutoExpandParent(false);
  };

  const onCheck = (checkedKeysValue) => {
    console.log("onCheck", checkedKeysValue);
    setCheckedKeys(checkedKeysValue);
  };

  const onSelect = (selectedKeysValue, info) => {
    console.log("onSelect", info);
    setSelectedKeys(selectedKeysValue);
  };
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const checked = [];

    treeData.forEach((data) => {
      data.children.forEach((item) => {
        if (item.checked) {
          checked.push(item.key);
        }
      });
    });
    setCheckedKeys(checked);
  }, []);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (searchValue) {
      const filteredData = filteredTreeData(
        treeData,
        searchValue,
        checkedKeys,
        setExpandedKeys
      );
      setTree([...filteredData]);
    } else {
      setTree(treeData);
      // setExpandedKeys([]);
    }
  }, [searchValue, checkedKeys]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Search
        style={{ marginBottom: 8 }}
        placeholder="Search"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setSearchValue(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <Tree
        checkable
        onExpand={onExpand}
        expandedKeys={expandedKeys}
        autoExpandParent={autoExpandParent}
        onCheck={onCheck}
        checkedKeys={checkedKeys}
        onSelect={onSelect}
        selectedKeys={selectedKeys}
        treeData={tree}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

[CodeSandBox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/controlled-tree-antd-4-19-1-forked-hv2cdv?file=/index.js:2524-4538)

Answer (score 0):

**Edited Response to fix uncheck issue**

If I understood the question correctly, Is the issue with the fact that previous checked items are getting cleared on search and selection of new one?

I think the solution would be to use 2 different separate trees one for filtered and the other for normal.

Did some code changes on top of the sandbox code shared.

1. I have added a new tree when searchedValue is present.
2. On checking/unchecking the new filtered tree, the actual entire tree's checked values get updated
3. When the searched value is empty it would show the actual entire tree
4. **Created a filteredKeys list to solve uncheck issue. Now I am able to select and unselect.**

If you play around and refactor a bit, you should be able to achieve what you want.

Adding the same code below.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Tree, Input } from "antd";

const { Search } = Input;
const treeData = [
  {
    title: "AP Watchlists",
    key: "AP Watchlists",
    children: [
      { title: "Colo Open Data", key: "Colo Open Data", checked: true },

      {
        title: "Department and trade",
        key: "Department and trade",
        checked: true
      },
      {
        title: "North List",
        key: "North List",
        checked: true
      },
      { title: "People's Daily", key: "People's Daily", checked: true }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "Af Watchlists",
    key: "Af Watchlists",
    children: [
      {
        title: "Service Wanted List",
        key: "Service Wanted List",
        checked: true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "EM Watchlists",
    key: "EM Watchlists",
    children: [
      {
        title: "National Financing",
        key: "National Financing",
        checked: true
      },
      {
        title: "Arabia List",
        key: "Arabia List",
        checked: true
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    title: "Assets List",
    key: "Assets List",
    children: [
      {
        title: "National List",
        key: "National List",
        checked: true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "New Watchlists",
    key: "New Watchlists",
    children: [
      { title: "FATR", key: "FATR", checked: true },
      { title: "Internal", key: "Internal", checked: true },
      {
        title: "OC List (Covers 73 Lists)",
        key: "OC List (Covers 73 Lists)",
        checked: true
      },
      { title: "UN", key: "UN", checked: true },
      {
        title: "Security List (Covers 18 Lists)",
        key: "Security List (Covers 18 Lists)",
        checked: true
      }
    ]
  }
];

const Demo = () => {
  const hasSearchTerm = (n, searchTerm) =>
    n.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
  const filterData = (arr, searchTerm, keys) => {
    const result = arr?.filter(
      (n) =>
        hasSearchTerm(n.title, searchTerm) ||
        filterData(n.children, searchTerm, keys)?.length > 0
    );
    result &&
      result.forEach((node) => {
        if (keys.indexOf(node?.key) === -1) keys.push(node?.key);
      });
    return result;
  };

  function filteredTreeData(data, searchString, checkedKeys, setExpandedTree) {
    let keysToExpand = [];
    const keys = [];
    const filteredData = searchString
      ? filterData(data, searchString, keys).map((n) => {
          keysToExpand.push(n.key);
          return {
            ...n,
            children: filterData(n.children, searchString, keys)
          };
        })
      : data;
    setExpandedTree([...keysToExpand]);
    setFilteredKeys(keys);
    return filteredData;
  }

  const [expandedKeys, setExpandedKeys] = useState([]);
  const [checkedKeys, setCheckedKeys] = useState([]);
  const [filteredCheckedKeys, setFilteredCheckedKeys] = useState([]);
  const [selectedKeys, setSelectedKeys] = useState([]);
  const [autoExpandParent, setAutoExpandParent] = useState(true);
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");
  const [tree, setTree] = useState(treeData);
  const [filteredTree, setFilteredTree] = useState([]);
  const [filteredKeys, setFilteredKeys] = useState([]);

  const onExpand = (expandedKeysValue) => {
    // console.log("onExpand", expandedKeysValue); // if not set autoExpandParent to false, if children expanded, parent can not collapse.
    // or, you can remove all expanded children keys.

    setExpandedKeys(expandedKeysValue);
    setAutoExpandParent(false);
  };

  const onCheck = (checkedKeysValue) => {
    // console.log("onCheck", checkedKeysValue);
    // console.log("checkedKeys", checkedKeys);
    setCheckedKeys(checkedKeysValue);
  };

  const onFilteredTreeCheck = (checkedKeysValue) => {
    // console.log("onFilterCheck", checkedKeysValue);
    // console.log("filteredcheckedKeys", filteredCheckedKeys);
    setFilteredCheckedKeys(checkedKeysValue);
    const baseTreeKeys = [...checkedKeys].filter(
      (node) => filteredKeys.indexOf(node) === -1
    );
    console.log("baseTreeKeys", baseTreeKeys);
    console.log("checkedKeysValue", checkedKeysValue);
    setCheckedKeys([...checkedKeysValue, ...baseTreeKeys]);
  };

  const onSelect = (selectedKeysValue, info) => {
    console.log("onSelect", info);
    setSelectedKeys(selectedKeysValue);
  };
  // React.useEffect(() => {
  //   const checked = [];

  //   treeData.forEach((data) => {
  //     data.children.forEach((item) => {
  //       if (item.checked) {
  //         checked.push(item.key);
  //       }
  //     });
  //   });
  //   setCheckedKeys(checked);
  // }, []);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredKeys([]);
    if (searchValue) {
      const filteredData = filteredTreeData(
        treeData,
        searchValue,
        checkedKeys,
        setExpandedKeys
      );
      setFilteredTree([...filteredData]);
    } else {
      setTree(treeData);
      // setExpandedKeys([]);
    }
  }, [searchValue, checkedKeys]);

  console.log("filteredCHeckedValues", filteredCheckedKeys);
  console.log("existing checked values", checkedKeys);

  return (
    <div>
      <Search
        style={{ marginBottom: 8 }}
        placeholder="Search"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setSearchValue(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      {searchValue ? (
        <Tree
          checkable
          onExpand={onExpand}
          expandedKeys={expandedKeys}
          autoExpandParent={autoExpandParent}
          onCheck={onFilteredTreeCheck}
          checkedKeys={filteredCheckedKeys}
          onSelect={onSelect}
          selectedKeys={selectedKeys}
          treeData={filteredTree}
        />
      ) : (
        <Tree
          checkable
          onExpand={onExpand}
          expandedKeys={expandedKeys}
          autoExpandParent={autoExpandParent}
          onCheck={onCheck}
          checkedKeys={checkedKeys}
          onSelect={onSelect}
          selectedKeys={selectedKeys}
          treeData={tree}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Let me know if this solves your issue. I am able to select multiple values in subsequent searches without loosing the checked ones.

Comment: I selected all checkboxes then I am searching some words in the search bar so why checkbox showing unselected

Comment: because users need to know the after search some field that field already selected or not but in your scenario whatever I am searching that result initially that coming with uncheck @aditya Akella

Comment: yeah you understand the issue but in your solution what issue is  for example, if I want to uncheck some fields after search then it will not work if I search that filed in the search bar if all fields are showing unchecked initially so who I will know which filed already select what not then I am able to update

Comment: @devdeveloper - Alright let me try to edit the solution to fix your concern

Comment: @devdeveloper - I have updated the solution to work with uncheck as well. Please test. other than some minor refactoring, main solution that you need should be present. Please give a vote up & select as right answer if this works

Comment: ok i will check

Comment: I checked sorry I think you mismatched the check field with search vale or not search value because I am seeing when initially I dint check any field then I searched and checked that check one box then I cleared search bar value that checks box showing uncheck you done like both check box value are different

Comment: i need to make like both check value is the same if I check or uncheck it not matter if I check after search or before search but in your case after search and before search value getting like different it will not work in right way

Comment: check my code once don't check anything just see before the search if the checkbox is already selected then alter search it will show selected then uncheck it then search see it get uncheck mean in both search and not search case not matter

Comment: @devdeveloper - The code i have pasted is very near to what you want right. You do have a way fwd now. I would suggest you go through the code .. see if you can fix whatever you think has to be, coz I am a bit occupied today

Comment: Thanks for your support i found some another to solve this issue that works fine for me I make changes in onCheck function

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the [API document](https://ant.design/components/tree/#Tree-props), `filterTreeNode` will keep keys from the tree node, and will not hide it.

```
filterTreeNode
Defines a function to filter treeNodes. When the function returns true, the corresponding treeNode will be checked
```

If you want to hide tree node, you will have to manually filter it first before before passing it to `Tree` in loop function, something like:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Tree, Input } from "antd";
const gData = [
  {
    key: "1",
    title: "title 1"
  },
  {
    key: "2",
    title: "title 2"
  },
  {
    key: "3",
    title: "title 3",
    children: [
      {
        key: "4",
        title: "title 4"
      },
      {
        key: "5",
        title: "title 5",
        children: [
          {
            key: "6",
            title: "title 6"
          },
          {
            key: "7",
            title: "title 7"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
const { Search } = Input;

const dataList = [];
const generateList = (data) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const node = data[i];
    const { key } = node;
    dataList.push({ key, title: key });
    if (node.children) {
      generateList(node.children);
    }
  }
};
generateList(gData);

const getParentKey = (key, tree) => {
  let parentKey;
  for (let i = 0; i < tree.length; i++) {
    const node = tree[i];
    if (node.children) {
      if (node.children.some((item) => item.key === key)) {
        parentKey = node.key;
      } else if (getParentKey(key, node.children)) {
        parentKey = getParentKey(key, node.children);
      }
    }
  }
  return parentKey;
};

const SearchTree = () => {
  const [expandedKeys, setExpandedKeys] = useState([]);
  const [autoExpandParent, setAutoExpandParent] = useState(true);
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");
  const [treeData, setTreeData] = useState(gData);

  const onExpand = (expandedKeys) => {
    setExpandedKeys(expandedKeys);
    setAutoExpandParent(false);
  };

  const onChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value?.toLowerCase();
    const expandedKeys = dataList
      .map((item) => {
        if (item.title.indexOf(value) > -1) {
          return getParentKey(item.key, gData);
        }
        return null;
      })
      .filter((item, i, self) => item && self.indexOf(item) === i);
    if (value) {
      const hasSearchTerm = (n) => n.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) !== -1;
      const filterData = (arr) =>
        arr?.filter(
          (n) => hasSearchTerm(n.title) || filterData(n.children)?.length > 0
        );
      const filteredData = filterData(gData).map((n) => {
        return {
          ...n,
          children: filterData(n.children)
        };
      });

      setTreeData(filteredData);
      setExpandedKeys(expandedKeys);
      setSearchValue(value);
      setAutoExpandParent(true);
    } else {
      setTreeData(gData);
      setExpandedKeys([]);
      setSearchValue("");
      setAutoExpandParent(false);
    }
  };

  const filterTreeNode = (node) => {
    const title = node.title.props.children[2];
    const result = title.indexOf(searchValue) !== -1 ? true : false;
    console.log(searchValue);
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  };

  const loop = (data) => 
    data.map((item) => {
      const index = item.title.indexOf(searchValue);
      const beforeStr = item.title.substr(0, index);
      const afterStr = item.title.substr(index + searchValue.length);
      const title =
        index > -1 ? (
          <span>
            {beforeStr}
            <span className="site-tree-search-value">{searchValue}</span>
            {afterStr}
          </span>
        ) : (
          <span>{item.title}</span>
        );
      if (item.children) {
        return { title, key: item.key, children: loop(item.children) };
      }

      return {
        title,
        key: item.key
      };
    });

  return (
    <div>
      <Search
        style={{ marginBottom: 8 }}
        placeholder="Search"
        onChange={onChange}
      />
      <Tree
        onExpand={onExpand}
        expandedKeys={expandedKeys}
        autoExpandParent={autoExpandParent}
        treeData={loop(treeData)}
        filterTreeNode={filterTreeNode}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<SearchTree />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Comment: this is not about highlighting the code this is about checked node issue means if you search some value in the search bar then you check or uncheck and field so all previously selected fields get unselected

Comment: I think you lost the OP as this has nothing to do with the issue.